# How do I index a value if there is no column title?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to plot from the dataframe, with X being the boolean and y being the mean.

```
df.plot(x = 'true/false', y = 'mean', kind = 'bar')
```

However, it returns KeyError of 'true/false'

```
              mean
true/false
         1     0.6
         0     0.7
```

And then I tried

```
df.column
```

It only returns the 'mean'

What should I do to plot?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `x` and set `use_index=1`:

```
df.plot(use_index=True, y='mean', kind='bar')
```